Who are the three civilians in this postcard (1933) from the Rococo Sanssouci Palace in Potsdam
I have this postcard from 1933 that I intend to use on my website about Berlin and the surrounding area, but I'm a little unsure of what it is that you see in the picture. It is clearly from the Rococo Sanssouci Palace in Potsdam, where "Soldaten der Reichswehr" and three civilians are lined up, but what is the reason and who are the three civilians? Can anyone answer that?
Reichswehr was the name for the German army in the period from 1919 to 1935 during the Weimar Republic and the beginning of Nazi Germany.
https://www.weesp.dk/Potsdam_en_de.htm?
https://www.weesp.dk/Berlin_Vaerd_at_besoege_en.htm


Can you make a higher resolution image? It's difficult to make details out on a scale much smaller than an actual postcard.

Can also be found here: https://www.akpool.de/ansichtskarten/32648519-foto-ansichtskarte-postkarte-potsdam-schloss-sanssouci-soldaten-der-reichswehr-in-uniformen-gruppenbild

I'm sorry but no.

In 1933, the successor of German Emperor Wilhelm II, Prince Louis Ferdinand of Prussia, lived in Sanssouci Palace in Potsdam
He was married to Grand Duchess Kira Kirillovna of Russia. Could it be them and then another relative?

LF and KK were married in 1938.
